# How do I clarify a multi-part identifier when updating a column from one database to another?

Tags: sql, sql-server

`Database2` is getting an error

> multi-part identifier could not be bound

from the query and I can't figure out why this is the case. I've looked at other posts but am having trouble finding an exact answer to what I'm doing wrong.

My goal is to replace a column of data from Database 2, to Database 1 that is between a time period.

Here's an example of what I am doing:

```
UPDATE Table1
SET Database1.dbo.Table1.Value1 = Database2.dbo.Table1.Value1
FROM Database1.dbo.Table1
INNER JOIN Database2.dbo.Table1.Value1 ON (Database1.dbo.Table1.Value1 = Database2.dbo.Table1.Value1)
WHERE  Database1.dbo.Table1.Value1.Date_Time BETWEEN '2002-12-09 14:00:00.000' AND '2013-06-20 14:00:00.000';
```

Comment: might be a dumd question but have you verified that both columns are in both tables? Also aliasing your objects will make this more readable

Comment: `INNER JOIN Database2.dbo.Table1.Value1` you join objects, not columns. So `.Value1` certainly doesn't belong there. Also agree with Doug, aliasing is your friend. You should only _need_ any fully-qualified reference once.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by aliasing? Sorry, I'm a little new to SQL. And I have verified that both columns are in both tables =)

Comment: There's also `where Database1.dbo.Table1.Value1.Date_Time`. So that's.. `database.schema.object.column... date_time??` What is `date_time`? SQL will think you mean `linkedServer.Database.Schema.object.column`.

Comment: [Short aliasing tutorial](https://www.sqltutorial.org/sql-alias/)

Answer (score 1):

This is just a syntax issue.  Alias both tables.

```
UPDATE d1_table
SET d1_table.Value1 = d2_table.Value1
FROM Database1.dbo.Table1 d1_table
INNER JOIN Database2.dbo.Table1 d2_table
ON d1_table.Value1 = d2_table.Value1)
WHERE  d1_table.Value1 BETWEEN '2002-12-09 14:00:00.000' AND '2013-06-20 14:00:00.000';
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to join tables ot columns with tables

```
UPDATE t1
    SET 
       t1.Value1 = t2.Value1
        FROM Database1.dbo.Table1 t1
        INNER JOIN (SELECT Value1 FROM Database2.dbo.Table1) t2
        ON ( t1.Value1 = t2.Value1)
        WHERE  t1.Date_Time BETWEEN '2002-12-09 14:00:00.000' AND '2013-06-20 14:00:00.000';
```